# Apache tomcat no reject threads

Tags: tomcat, cxf, executorservice, apache-httpcomponents, threadpoolexecutor

I have implemented a Web Service with Apache CXF runtimes and run on Tomcat

I want to limit the number of request in queue before it start to run.

But I launch a performance test (many request at the same time) and I observe that server doesn't reject the remaining requests.

This is my configuration in server.xml File:

In this example, I don't want that the request number 11, remains in the queue any second.
Otherwise, I want receive a message in the client instantly.

```
<Service name="Catalina">
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool"
              namePrefix="catalina-exec-" 
              maxThreads="8" 
              maxQueueSize="10"  //Limit of queue, request 11 must reject
              minSpareThreads="8"/>

    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
              port="186" 
              protocol="HTTP/1.1"
              connectionTimeout="20000"
              redirectPort="8443" />

    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
              SSLEnabled="true" 
              clientAuth="false" 
              port="86" 
              protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
              scheme="https" 
              secure="true"
              sslProtocol="TLS"
              keystoreFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\keystore"/>
```

In the Executor documentation say the following definition for the maxQueueSize parameter:

```
(int) The maximum number of runnable tasks that can queue up awaiting execution before we reject them. Default value is Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

What do I do wrong because the request doesn't reject?